# Argument of type 'typeof import' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Auth'

Tags: react, typescript, firebase, auth, cloud

Eu estou fazendo uma aplicação que utiliza **Firebase** para a autenticação, porém retorna na tela o seguinte erro não está funcionando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código

Configuração Firebase:

```
// This import loads the firebase namespace along with all its type information.
 import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

// These imports load individual services into the firebase namespace.  
 import * as auth from 'firebase/auth';
 import * as database from 'firebase/database';

 const firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
     authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
     databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
     projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
     storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
     messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
     appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
};

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  export { firebase, auth, database };
```

A chamada para realizar a autenticação com o Google:

```
 import { firebase, auth } from "../services/firebase";

 const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

 auth.signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  history.push("/rooms/new");
 });
```

Também recebo este erro no código ao realizar a chamada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem certeza que esta usando a função corretamente.  Na documentação (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithpopup) parece que `auth.signInWithPopup` so tem um parâmetro, `provider`

Comment: Tentei e recebi esse erro: 

** 2-3 argumentos eram esperados, mas 1 foram obtidos. **